# Accessing object in javascript issue

Tags: javascript

This is the result of my `console.log(params)`:

```
currency_id: false
customer_id: 127505
"payment[account_name]": ""
"payment[iban]": ""
"payment[method]": "adyen_sepa"
store_id: "1"
```

I got this from ajax call and when I am doing this `onSuccess` :

```
 console.log(params.customer_id);  // I got the right value
 console.log(params.payment['method'])  // I am getting undefined
 var obj = "payment['method']";
 console.log(params.obj)  // still undefined
```

How can I get teh value from  `payment[method]`   ? Thnx

Comment: hi @Tushar , my question is different, I have as key an `array`, In that post is just a key . Thnx

Comment: No. All keys in JS objects are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little confusing because the key name has brackets in it, so while you were close with your original code, try this instead:

```
params['payment[method]']
```

Using bracket notation you place the key name (all key names in JS objects are strings) in quotes.

Comment: thnx its working :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get teh value from  payment[method] ? Thnx

Use *bracket notation*

```
var obj = "payment[method]";
console.log(params[obj])
```

**Demo**

```js
var params = {
  currency_id: false,
  customer_id: 127505,
  "payment[account_name]": "",
  "payment[iban]": "",
  "payment[method]": "adyen_sepa",
  store_id: "1"
}

var obj = "payment[method]";
console.log(params[obj])
```

Comment: Still `undefined` :)

Comment: @Chester check the demo.

Comment: @Chester It should be `"payment[method]"` instead of `"payment['method']"`.

Comment: thnx its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
var output = {
    currency_id: false,
    customer_id: 127505,
    "payment[account_name]": "",
    "payment[iban]": "",
    "payment[method]": "adyen_sepa",
    store_id: "1"
}
console.log(output['payment[method]']);
```